# Recover From Bad Flash, Recovery Gone, ODIN no go Galaxy S6 Verizon

Tags: samsung, odin, verizon

I have a GS6 on 5.0.2. I wanted to get rid of my root and go back to stock firmware while upgrading to 5.1.1. So I flashed official 5.1.1 using odin but it failed. Recovery mode no longer works.

Odin seems to always fail. I can go back to download mode or be instructed to restore via Verizon's software assistant. Verizon's software is not supported on Windows 10 and won't detect my device on Windows 8.1. Smart switch is not recognized.  Here is what odin has to say. It fails at the system.img

Verizon G920V

```
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Binary Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 0)
<ID:0/004> Added!!
<ID:0/004> Odin engine v(ID:3.1100)..
<ID:0/004> File analysis..
<ID:0/004> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/004> Initialzation..
<ID:0/004> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/004> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/004> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/004> sboot.bin
<ID:0/004> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/004> cm.bin
<ID:0/004> boot.img
<ID:0/004> recovery.img
<ID:0/004> system.img
<ID:0/004> 
<ID:0/004> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

I have tried multiple firmwares. If I could find a pit file to flash I would.

Anyway, I went to Verizon and they are sending me a replacement in two days. In download mode it still says that the firmware is official. However it also says samsung custom. (Assuming the root) I don't know if Verizon will backcharge me for this. Is there any way to get rid of the custom status? When I put it in the box to return it I'll leave it on the System Software Update Failed screen.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone finds this in the future. I figured out how to fix this. I had have a working phone to install verizon's upgrade assitant. It would not work from the exe I found on the internet. From there I had to install it in a virtual machine because it did not like Win 10. From there I simply plugged in my device and it restored it. Use this method if odin doesn't work. I WILL NEVER ROOT AGAIN!